# Skype puts macOS users on mute for all calls on macOS Sierra

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, microphone, skype

All of the Mac users in my organisation get put on mute whenever they make or receive Skype calls. None of the Windows users are affected.  It mutes their microphones (headset or built-in) when their outgoing call is connected, but if you add a second call to that they stay off mute.

Their microphones are similarly muted whenever they answer a Skype call, whether or not it's a group call.

We're on Skype 16.3.240 right now, but it's been the case for a few months now.

Comment: Can you try it with the Skype web app?

Comment: Where you say "but if you add a second call to that they stay off mute" do you mean that adding a second call renders all the users in that conversation non-muted?

Comment: @DAVincent, sorry that wasn't clear - I am muted (not the other person on the call) when I answer or make the call. If I then unmute myself, say hi, and then add a second call to the conference then I stay non-muted. Further calls don't change your mute state - if I'm in a conference call on mute I stay on mute, if I'm talking I stay non-muted.

Comment: @DAVincent is there a Skype web app for Skype for Business??

Comment: Martin, I haven't tried Skype for Business, so knowing Microsoft there may well be no web app.

Comment: No problem.  I just talked to a colleague who has used Skype for Business, and he says there does not seem to be a Skype for Web option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to have been fixed in the latest patch from Microsoft.